# Find-Module not working from inside function/module running as a scheduled task

Tags: powershell

I have several scheduled tasks which run functions exported from my PowerShell module(s). The scheduled task runs a function which calls the `Find-Module` command to locate a module in a custom-registered repository; not PSGallery.

Here is the command being executed inside the function:

```
Function Foo {
    $ModuleName = "SomeName"
    $Repo = "MyRepository"
    $result = Find-Module -Name $ModuleName -Repository $Repo
}
```

The command doesn't fail, rather the `$result` variable ends up being `Null`.

Here is the output from my `Get-PSRepository`:

```
Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/
MyRepository              Trusted              \\server01\PSGalleryLocal
```

If I remove the `-Repository $Repo` parameter and rely on using the built-in `PSGallery` repository, it will find the module without issue.

If I run the `Foo` function from a PowerShell command-line it will find the module registered to `$Repo` and work as designed.

Any idea why a registered repository run inside a function as part of a scheduled task won't recognize the custom repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PSRepository is registered *per user* and there is no system wide option, unfortunately.

You will have to register the repository as the user you're running the scheduled task as. That could be the `SYSTEM` account as well.

You could add that to your scheduled task (register the repo if it doesn't exist). You could also do it as a separate process, but either way every user that needs the repo will need it registered for them.

Comment: Eventually I'll use PSGallery for my published module but in following 'best practices' I've been trying to rely on my own repo with all the publishing/tweaking going on. I'll give that a try. Cheers.

Comment: Just to be clear, you would suggest registering the repo using a "runas" command and specify `system` as the user? I reviewed the docs on the command and there isn't a built-in option for an `identity` for the repo registration.

Comment: @JasonShave you can use `runas` if it's not a special account like `SYSTEM`. To make things easier I usually open a `cmd` or `powershell` prompt as the user I want so I don't have to keep authenticating, then I run stuff from there. If it's a special user, you can use `psexec` from SysInternals, or just run your command as a scheduled task (one time thing) running as that user. `Register-PSRepository` doesn't offer any way itself to register repos for another user.